# how to write SQL to count the number of mobile/tablet/desktop users?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, count

I have a table looking like,

```
VisitorId   date            deviceType
1           2018-12-11      mobile
2           2018-12-11      mobile
3           2018-12-11      desktop
4           2018-12-11      mobile
1           2018-12-12      desktop
2           2018-12-12      mobile
1           2018-12-20      mobile
2           2018-12-20      tablet
...
```

Each row records the info of a new visitor.

I'm trying to write a query to output **the number of mobile/desktop/tablet based on date**.
The expected output should be like the following

```
date        numOfDesktop      numOfTablet      numOfMobile
2018-12-11  1                 0                3
2018-12-12  1                 0                1
2018-12-20  0                 1                1
...
```

I have wrote a SQL like this, but the syntax is wrong.

```
SELECT 
  date,
  COUNT(deviceType= "mobile") As numOfMobile,
  COUNT(deviceType= "desktop") AS numOfDesktop,
  COUNT(deviceType= "tablet") AS numOfTablet
FROM 
  tableName
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date ASC
```

I have no experience in SQL, can someone help me craft a working SQL query?

Comment: Did you try to learn what is the correct syntax?

Comment: What do you mean "the syntax is wrong"?  The syntax looks correct for MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the right idea, although, as you've seen, this is not valid syntax. You could use a `case` expression though:

```
SELECT 
  date,
  COUNT(CASE deviceType WHEN 'mobile' THEN 1 END) As numOfMobile,
  COUNT(CASE deviceType WHEN 'desktop' THEN 1 END) AS numOfDesktop,
  COUNT(CASE deviceType WHEN 'tablet' THEN 1 END) AS numOfTablet
FROM 
  tableName
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

Your were supposed to use `SUM` inplace of `COUNT` as when the condition within is true 1 is return and when it is false 0, so summing those values will be as if you were counting them based on the condition. You should also make sure that there is no time in the dates.

```
SELECT 
  DATE(`date`) `date`,
  SUM(deviceType="mobile") As numOfMobile,
  SUM(deviceType="desktop") AS numOfDesktop,
  SUM(deviceType="tablet") AS numOfTablet
FROM 
  tableName
GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
ORDER BY DATE(`date`);
```

To use count do something like:

```
SELECT 
  DATE(`date`) `date`,
  COUNT(IF(deviceType="mobile", 1, NULL)) As numOfMobile,
  COUNT(IF(deviceType="desktop", 1, NULL)) AS numOfDesktop,
  COUNT(IF(deviceType="tablet", 1, NULL)) AS numOfTablet
FROM 
  tableName
GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
ORDER BY DATE(`date`);
```

In this case when the condition is false a null is return and the count function is not going to take that into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like as:

```
SELECT 
    date,
    sum(deviceType= "desktop") As numOfDesktop,
    sum(deviceType= "tablet") As numOfTablet,
    sum(deviceType = 'mobile') as numOfMobile
FROM 
    tableName
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date ASC
```